# Does a C language client library for Cassandra exist?

Tags: c, cassandra

I wish I could use Cassandra for a project where only C language is used.

I tried to find a mature C client library for Cassandra, with no luck.

Shall I try a C++ one instead, like http://github.com/posulliv/libcassandra, or does one exist?

Comment: AFAIK there is no C support in Thrift. So I dont think you will find any C library

Answer (score 2):

At least in Thrift trunk, there is C glib support, which means it's possible to make a C client for Cassandra.  It's probably not well tested yet.

posulliv/libcassandra was never completed and only supports Cassandra 0.6.  It lacks several features like super column support, for example.

I also started a [C++ client that supports Cassandra 0.7](https://github.com/thobbs/Coroebus), but it's still half-baked at the moment.  Most of the Cassandra API is supported.  At the very least, it can be a good example of working with the Thrift API.  Of course, if you're capable of contributing to the project or starting a C client, I think many people would appreciate that.

Comment: Hi Tyler. Coroebus looks promising ! Didn't decided yet the solution. Creating a C client is a great challenge, i'm beginning in Cassandra and Thrift sounds far from simple. However I like challenges, so who knows ! BTW, your project lacks a LICENSE file ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yeah, I need to put one in there.  It will be BSD licensed.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a very basic proof-of-concept C client for Cassandra and put it up on [github](https://github.com/pjh/cassandra-c-client). It relies on the barely-documented C language support in Thrift (as mentioned in previous answers). This client is not mature by any means, but demonstrates how to use the C files generated by Thrift, and offers some basic functionality; it might be a useful stepping stone towards a more serious C client.

Answer (score 0):

I managed generating C code from the Cassandra trunk Thrift file.
I obtained the following files :

- cassandra.c
- cassandra.h
- cassandra_types.c
- cassandra_types.h

No main() function there, I guess these should be linked and used as a library, but I found no API documentation or whatsoever.

The samples in thrift/lib/c_glib/test do not show any client test source...
Will look into this more deeply !

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and hopefully this helps -
http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/

Answer (score -1):

There is already a C++ cassandra API called libQtCassandra
http://snapwebsites.org/project/libqtcassandra#Download