# Are there any C bindings/libs for Apache Cassandra?

Tags: binding, cassandra, shared-libraries

Are there any C bindings/libs for Apache Cassandra? Or, alternatively, is there a way to use the C++ binding/library "libcql" with C, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure C and cassandra dont mix well because there isn't much support for C in the Thrift protocol. I dont know of any binary C APIs either.

There is a 'proof-of-concept' [C API](https://github.com/pjh/cassandra-c-client) but the author highlights that this shouldn't be used in production. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602653/does-a-c-language-client-library-for-cassandra-exist) has another C++ library mentioned, but it looks like there isn't much support for C.